# Creating a navigation bar with links to local HTML files

Tags: html

On my website there is a navigation bar and when I click on the navigation links it needs to go to another file I have stored locally on a USB.

How I would do this?

For example:

- Home
- About
- FunFacts
- Contact

Say someone wanted to click on "about".  How do I go about linking it on my usb to the about page (a separate html file)?

Answer (score 3):

You would need to create a main container for your navigation bar and use `<a>` tags for the links.  Depending on how you currently have your files stored, you would have to set the `href` attributes of the links appropriately.

For example:

```
<html>
  <body>
    <ul class="navbar">
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a href="home.html">Home</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a href="about.html">About</a>
      </li>
      ...
    </ul>
  </body>
</html>
```

In the example, I use a `<ul>` element as a container since it's a list of  navigation items.  You could also choose to use a `<div>`.

For each subitem, I wrap it in a `<li>` which is a list item.  On each item, I use the aforementioned `<a>` tags.

These are the HTML tags which actually create the link.  The `href` attribute of the `<a>` tag tells the browser where to go when the user clicks the link.

**Example**

Lets assume you're on the `home.html` page.

In the case of the example, the "About" link tells the browser to go to the `about.html` page in the same directory as the current (`home.html`) page.

If the "about.html" file were stored elsewhere, you could:

- Use `..` to reference the parent directory (the one that contains the current directory) like `../about.html` which means find `about.html` page in the folder above the one that the `home.html` is in.
- Use `subdir/` to reference a child directory (a directory that is in the same place as the current file) like `pages/about.html` which means find the `about.html` page in the `pages` folder in the same directory as the current file.
- Use `/` to reference the root of the webpage.  This is normally appended to the domain name but is less relevant for files on your local computer (accessed via `file://`).  Depending on your browser and security settings, you may be able to use an absolute path like `file://path/to/about.html`, but I don't think that works in most modern browsers for security reasons.

**More examples**

- webpage/

  - home.html
  - about.html
  - fun/

    - funfacts.html
  - contact.html

If you're in `home.html`, `about.html`, or `contact.html`, you'd use:

```
<a href="home.html">Home</a>
<a href="about.html">Home</a>
<a href="fun/funfacts.html">Home</a>
<a href="contact.html">Home</a>
```

If you're in `funfacts.html` you'd use:

```
<a href="../home.html">Home</a>
<a href="../about.html">Home</a>
<a href="funfacts.html">Home</a>
<a href="../contact.html">Home</a>
```

Answer (score 2):

well, copy the other html file/s (from the usb stick) to the same directory as the html file you are starting with and then change the navbar links

Answer (score 0):

Guys im feel like a total idiot I was trying to do I/Napoleon2 when I  needed to do just napoleon2.html I didn't relize my mistake till looking over your guys source code. Thanks everyone and best of luck to you in your future coding!